# Google hosted jQuery list

Tags: jquery

Where is there a good link to a list of Google hosted jQuery lib's?

I'm using this the following script and it works great:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I'm currently trying to get a slider going but it's not working so I'm looking for a list of google hosted jQuery libs, plugins, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find CDN entries that google hosts here: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/) has a full list.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries

Answer (score 1):

For anyone taking a look at this now, Google migrated most of the content from code.google.com to developers.google.com.  The new url for the Google Libraries API is https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?csw=1#Libraries.